# Can CPU performance be permanently be degraded by running at high temperatures?

Tags: performance, cpu, temperature

My question is specifically if a processor can perform worse after extended periods of being too hot. 
I've had my laptop for four years and my cpu would regularly get to 85C+ watching videos or using skype. 
Lately it seems like my computer is gradually slowing down and I'm even having audio issues. It won't go back to how it was. It's not the OS because I run a dual boot and it's performing horribly on Linux too.

Comment: Heat will have no/very very little effect on speed. How old is the compiter, what OS, how full the hdd, etc.etc.

Comment: At those temps I'd say your heat sink or CPU fan may not be operating properly. When it's running really hot like that, it can definitely cause it to act funny. My old laptop would do the same thing. My CPU fan was bad, it would get too hot, and then audio would become a buzzing noise and it would freeze momentarily because it was too hot.

Comment: If it's constantly that hot then your heat sink and fan are too dusty and/or has problems. Go for a cleaning service first

Comment: Every cpu model has a different thermal design limit which it can operate safely at, post the model of CPU.

Comment: It's rather old and uncommon. It's an AMD Athlon II P360. Compared to benchmarks of newer CPUs it performs about a tenth as well as a recent Intel core i5. So I think it's just the CPU's poor performance at this point.

Answer (score 0):

The CPU itself is very unlikely to permanently degrade in performance by overheating. Most relatively modern CPUs have a thermal protection in the form of emergency shutdown and throttling. You seem to be getting the effects of the latter.

But if your cooling system is faulty then it is likely that not only the cpu gets hot, and electrolytic capacitors do degrade when heated too much. If it happened - this will affect system stability, but not the speed again.

I'd recommend to disassemble the PC, clean the heat sinks and fans, check if the fans rotate freely and are operational